# How to parse text from anonymous block in AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I'm parsing site content using AngleSharp and i've got an issue with anonymous block.

See the sample code:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(@"<body>
<div class='product'>
    <a href='#'><img src='img1.jpg' alt=''></a>
    Hello, world
    <div class='comments-likes'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='product'>
    <a href='#'><img src='img2.jpg' alt=''></a>
    Yet another helloworld
    <div class='comments-likes'>25</div>
</div>
<body>");

var products = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.product");
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var productTitle = product.Text();
    productTitle.Dump();
}
```

So, productTitle contains numbers from div.comments-likes, output is:

> Hello, world   1
>
> Yet another helloworld   25

I've tried something like `product.FirstElementChild.NextElementSibling.Text();` but next sibling for link element is div.comments-likes, not anonymous block. It shows:

> 1
>
> 25

So, anonymous blocks are skipped. :(

The best workaround i've found is deleting all preventing blocks, for my example:

```
product.QuerySelector(".comments-likes").Remove();
var productTitle = product.Text().Trim();
```

Is better way for parsing text from anonymous block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text is modeled as a `TextNode`, it is a *type of node* beside element, comment node, processing instruction, etc. That's why `NextElementSibling` you tried didn't include the text in the result since it intended to return elements only, as the name suggests.

You can get text nodes located directly within product `div` by traversing through the `div`'s `ChildNodes` and then filter by `NodeType`, for example :

```
var products = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.product");
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var productTitle = product.ChildNodes
                              .First(o => o.NodeType == AngleSharp.Dom.NodeType.Text 
                                            && o.TextContent.Trim() != "");
    Console.WriteLine(productTitle.TextContent.Trim());
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPRd43)</kbd>**

Notice that newlines between elements are also text nodes, so we need to filter those out in the demo above.

Comment: Thanks for explanations!

Comment: @har07  Could you see this question, please, [remove all rows from the HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784594/how-is-it-possible-to-remove-all-rows-from-the-html-table-using-anglesharp)?

Comment: Can you make a dotnetfiddle demo that reproduce the problem? My simple test seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAk1W5