# How is it possible to remove all rows from the HTML table using anglesharp?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

How is it possible to remove all rows from the HTML table using anglesharp?

I am trying to remove all rows in table. [I've read this documentation](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Questions.html#how-can-i-remove-all-elements-matching-a-certain-selector), however, rows are not removed.

My code looks like this:

```
public void DeleteRows(IElement table)
{
    foreach (var row in table?.QuerySelectorAll("tr"))
    {
        row.Remove();
    }
    var lengthAfterDeletion = table?.QuerySelectorAll("tr")?.Length;
}
```

How is it possible to remove all rows from the HTML table using anglesharp?

Comment: Did you try "table.Rows.Remove(row);" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we figured it out in the meantime (see https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/838).

Just for future reference (in case somebody else runs into the same problem, which happens quite easily):

```
public void DeleteRows(IElement table)
{
    var rows = table?.QuerySelectorAll("tr").ToArray();
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        row.Remove();
    }
    var legnthAfterDeletion = table?.QuerySelectorAll("tr")?.Length;
}
```

The key is to get a static snapshot of the result before changing the DOM. Hence the `.ToArray()` which comes from LINQ and can be applied to any iterator.